# How can I show a MS-Access listbox row highlighted?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

How can I show a MS-Access listbox row highlighted? I'm using MS-Access 2007. I want the first row of a multiple-column listbox to be showed highlighted through VBA.
I tried `Me.LstSample.Selected(0) = True`, but it doesn't work.

The code:

```
Private Sub LstStation_AfterUpdate()
With Me.LstSample
    If IsNull(Me.LstStation) Then
        .RowSource = ""
    Else
        .RowSource = _
            "SELECT * FROM Samples WHERE S='" & Me.LstStation.Value & "'"
    End If
    Call .Requery
    If Not IsNull(Me.LstStation) Then
      Me.LstSample.Selected(0) = True
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It should work. Where did you put the line, what event? Can you step through to see if the event fires? As a note, do not use the form Open event, because the controls will not have initialized.

Comment: I put it in the AfterUpdate of another listbox. If the user selects a row in this (first) listbox, then in the AfterUpdate event code I resets the 'RowSource' property of the second listbox, do a 'Requery' and then the code I mentioned.

Comment: Edit your post to include the AfterUpdate event code. What you are describing should work just fine, so I'd guess there's something you are leaving out or there's a small error in your code.

Comment: I would imagine that it is not "not isnull". Have you tried commenting out the If line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally stripped the code and resetted the properties of the controls and now it works fine!

I'm figuring out what the differences are and will let you all know.

Comment: I finally found it. Because I set the ColumnHeads propery to True, the first row contains the headings, so to highlight the first (data)row I've to use LstSample.Selected(1)=True instead of LstSample.Selected(0)=True

Answer (score 0):

Try and change the

```
Me.LstSample.Selected(0) = True
```

to

```
Me.lstSample.SetFocus
Me.lstSample.ListIndex = 0
```

I'm not sure why the original code isn't working, but I tend to use the ListIndex property instead of the Selected property.

Answer (score 0):

I always set the value of the listbox:

```
  Me!lstMyListBox = Me!lstMyListBox.ItemData(0)
```